# Address multiple columns of data.frame with a single name

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm able to name specific columns of a dataframe, as in:

```
> x <- data.frame(t(1:3));
> names(x)[2] <- "X";
> x
 X1  X X3 
  1  2  3
> x$X
2
```

But when I do the following:

```
> names(x)[-1] <- "X";
> x
 X1  X  X
  1  2  3
```

Both columns are correctly named with "X", but I'm unable to address all the columns:

```
> x$X 
[1] 2
```

Is there any means of addressing multiple columns of the data.frame, using a single name -- and without *hard-coded* addressing, as in `x[2:3]`?

Comment: You don't need the semicolons in R.

Comment: Yep, but I like them (:

Comment: There is no sensible reason to have two data.frame columns with identical names.

Comment: Isn't it sensible to do `var$twocolumns` and get the set of columns selected?

Comment: @Rubens Not really, since the documentation states: "Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list."

Comment: @joran My will is to have a sub-`data.frame` in the `data.frame`. I find it pretty much reasonable.

Comment: And you can, just not using `[[` or `$`, that's all.

Comment: The risk is when you try to do something like `x$X <- 5`. With multiple columns sharing the same name, the result may be unexpected.

Comment: You could store it as a list: `df <- data.frame(X1 = 1, X = I(list(2:3)))`. And then access `df$X`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to store a matrix as a variable in a data frame. You have to protect the matrix by wrapping it inside `I()`, or the `data.frame` constructor function will turn it into multiple variables.

```
m <- matrix(1:20, nrow=5)
df <- data.frame(x=letters[1:5], m=I(m))
df$m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   16
[2,]    2    7   12   17
[3,]    3    8   13   18
[4,]    4    9   14   19
[5,]    5   10   15   20
```

This probably isn't a good idea though.

Comment: +1 for *giving the best approach -- despite of being a good idea*.

Comment: @Rubens, extremely curious here as to the application.  It could very well be that we are wrong that the task is very suitable for the application

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where this is favorable to a `list` or `array`

Comment: @SeñorO It's useful for model frames and model matrices. For example, `poly`, `bs` and `ns` return matrices giving the basis functions for the curves they fit. In this case, there is a good reason to keep the matrices distinct, as the basis functions are only meaningful when considered as a group.

Answer (score 3):

Use regex:

```
x[,grep("^X$",names(x))]
```

Answer (score 3):

there is no "direct" way to grab a column with the same name.  If you have two green crayons in a box, and you say "give me the green crayon" how would anyone know *which* crayon to give?

You can ask for all of them, but then you have to do some matching.   One option is using `grep` as @thomas has suggested.   You can use `%in%`

```
x[, names(x) %in% "X"]
```

I like using `%in%` because it allows you to do use a vector of selections, such as

```
x[, names(x) %in% c("X", "Y")]
```

I also, however, like to have unique column names ;)

```
names(x) <- make.names(names(x))
```

Comment: +1 Note: If/since length(RHS) is 1, `%in%` can be replaced by `==`. Not that there's anything bad/wrong about this.

Comment: +1 This is much more precise than the regular expression route.

Comment: +1 That's exactly the addressing schema I've been looking for. In fact, the whole question is how to have a sub-`data.frame` in a `data.frame`. I guess this is the right approach.

Comment: @Rubens, just as a point of best practice.  Generally, if you are finding yourself deliberately using the same column names, you might want to see if there is something about the general approach that could be improved

Comment: .@arun and I were just writing the same comment at the same time.  ;)

Comment: @Arun Yep, I found my way around with HongObiKanobi's answer.